# Consolidating an array of arrays into an object while merging values under a specific key (there are duplicates in the array)

Tags: javascript, arrays

Sorry about the confusing title but here is what I am trying to do.  I have this array:

```
let arr = [
    ["200.0", "SUPP"],
    ["200.0", "SUPP"],
    ["200.0", "SUPP"],
    ["200.0", "SUPP"],
    ["150.0", "DOG"],
    ["150.0", "DOG"],
    ["150.0", "DOG"],
    ["20.0", "CAT"],
    ["20.0", "CAT"],
    ["10000.0", "FRANK"]
]
```

I am trying to make it look like so:

```
const result = {
    "SUPP": ["200.0", "200.0", "200.0", "200.0"]
    "DOG": ["150.0", "150.0", "150.0"]
    "CAT": ["20.0", "20.0"]
    "FRANK": ["10000.0"]
}
```

I can get set pretty easily with this:

```
let obj = {}

for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    obj[arr[i][1]] = arr[i][0]
}
```

This is the output:

```
{ SUPP: '200.0', DOG: '150.0', CAT: '20.0', FRANK: '10000.0' }
```

I know reduce is the best bet here but I struggle with understanding it... I don't program much anymore and my mind is mush

Comment: IF <arr[i][1] does not exist in the object> THEN <set it as an empty array>, and then afterwards push the value to the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, reducing is basically equivalent to a loop (just a bit shorter), so you shouldn't feel obligated to use it. You can still use a loop, just make sure you push to an array instead of constantly reassigning the element:

```js
let obj = {}

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i ++) {
    let [val, key] = arr[i]
    if (!(key in obj)) {
        // not seen before, initialize to empty array
        obj[key] = []
    }
    // push to array
    obj[key].push(val)
}
```

Or, with the new [logical nullish assignment operator (??=)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment):

```js
let obj = {}

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i ++) {
    (obj[arr[i][1]] ??= []).push(arr[i][0])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `reduce` method for this and if the key exist in the accumulator use `push` and if it doesn't set its value to new array.

```js
let arr = [["200.0","SUPP"],["200.0","SUPP"],["200.0","SUPP"],["200.0","SUPP"],["150.0","DOG"],["150.0","DOG"],["150.0","DOG"],["20.0","CAT"],["20.0","CAT"],["10000.0","FRANK"]]

const result = arr.reduce((r, [v, k]) => {
  if (!r[k]) r[k] = [v];
  else r[k].push(v)
  return r;
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

using `Array.reduce`:

```js
let arr=[["200.0","SUPP"],["200.0","SUPP"],["200.0","SUPP"],["200.0","SUPP"],["150.0","DOG"],["150.0","DOG"],["150.0","DOG"],["20.0","CAT"],["20.0","CAT"],["10000.0","FRANK"]];


let result = arr.reduce((acc,e) =>{
    if(acc.hasOwnProperty(e[1]))
      acc[e[1]].push(e[0])
    else 
      acc[e[1]]=[e[0]]
    return acc
}
,{})

console.log(result)
```